# Problem calling parameterized MariaDB SP with LIMIT using PHP

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mariadb

I have been stumped with this and cannot find a working example or tutorial anywhere.

Given the following stored procedure:

**SQL**

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCECURE sp1(IN 'myoffset' INT, IN 'myrows' 
INT)
begin
select * from t1
limit 'myoffset', 'myrows'
END$$
delimiter
```

I am trying to call it from PHP like so:

... establish $conn, then

**PHP**

```
// ver1:
$sql = ( "SET @p0 = $tmp1;" . " SET @p1 = $tmp2;" . " 
CALL `sp1`(@p0, @p1);" );

//OR    

//ver2
$sql = "SET @p0 = `$tmp1`; SET @p1 = `$tmp2`; CALL 
`sp1`(@p0, @p1);";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Neither one works.  MariaDB complains that

> "Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @p1 = `25`; CALL `sp1`(@p0, @p1)' at line 2"

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is in `$tmp1`?

If it is a number, then the first one should work, but the second one does not make sense because it becomes

```
SET @p0 = `1234`;
```

I assume there is not a column or table named `1234`?  Keep in mind that backtics are for columns, tables, and database names.

If $tmp is the string `"a string"`, then you get

```
SET @p0 = a string;  -- strings need to be quoted here
```

or

```
SET @p0 = `a string`;  -- again that is treated as a column (etc) name.
```

After that, you have another problem:  Do not tack multiple statements together (separated by `;`); run them separately.

Finally, there is no need for `@p0`, etc:

```
$sql = "CALL `sp1`('$tmp1', '$tmp2')";
```

is sufficient.

Well, not quite.  If the values for $tmps came from the outside world, see the dreaded "SQL Injection" problem.

Oh, and what if

```
$tmp1 = "Don't do this";
```

Then you get

```
$sql = "CALL `sp1`('Don't do this', '$tmp2')";
```

Look at the single quotes.  There are 3 of them.  How will this be parsed?